# retrieving json value from json in java

Tags: java, android, json

```
 {"category1":"value1","category2":"value2"}
```

Kindly do not downvote. I am asking this question here, to get direct answers and move on.
 In android app I am trying to get the values or category1 and category 2 as follows, but I am getting errors. why ?

```
JSONParserPostGet jsonParser2 = new JSONParserPostGet();
JSONObject json = jsonParser2.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);

if (json != null) 
{   
String category1 = json.getString("category1"); 
String category2 = json.getString("category2");
}
```

Comment: what class is 'json' and what error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting null pointer exception.

Comment: If you get a null pointer on those statements then "json" isn't there.

Comment: could you edit your post and add relevant pieces of code

Comment: my bad, should have mentioned I am using it on android, where there are the json libraries. see the updated question.

Comment: @tony9099 If that's the only relevant code then `jsonParser2` isn't initialised, that's the only thing I can see which would cause a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, It is initialized. I just havnt included it in the question.

Comment: @tony9099 To be blunt, it's a NPE. You (should) have a stacktrace, and you have the full code, tracing backwards to find the cause of it shouldn't be difficult for you at all. From what you've posted already the error is being thrown before you even reach that part.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist thanks for being a genius.

Answer (score 1):

The code below just works fine. Please note that it is using org.json:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject("{\"category1\":\"value1\",\"category2\":\"value2\"}");
System.out.println(object.getString("category1"));
System.out.println(object.getString("category2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no JSON parser in the Java standard library. Try using [JSON in Java](http://json.org/java/).

Comment: my bad, should have mentions I am using it on android, where there are the json libraries. see the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

If your null pointer is on json, wrap it in a JSONException try catch and see if it gives you any more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add JSON Library manually in your code as given by Joshua Swank and follow

http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/